# Google API Oauth/Omniauth not verifying my application name or type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth to connect to the Google API for Oauth authentication.  I am passing xoauth_displayname with my application name and I'm getting the following error on the screen that allows access to the contacts API.

The application that directed you here claims to be "My Application Name". We are unable to verify this claim as the application runs on your computer, as opposed to a website. We recommend you deny access unless you trust the application.

The thing is, I setup the Client ID as a Web Application client ID so I'm really not sure why I'm getting this error.  Right above my Client ID in the API console it says:
"Client ID for web applications"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you set up your client ID, select "installed application" as opposed to the "web application" option. You'll have to do this if your application runs on a desktop or handheld device, the "web application" option will only work if making requests from an actual website or server side application.

I think the google API documentation is a little bit difficult to navigate around personally so not sure if you've found this page yet. But check out this page http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html and scroll down to the 'OAuth 2.0 for native applications' section. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, this is a web application.  That's why I don't quite understand it saying that it isn't.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Not sure it's what you want but if you wanted to have a look, I wrote a google storage gem that connects to the Google API via OAuth2 using a web application client ID last year but I didn't use Omniauth so not sure it's what you want.. Anyways, good luck https://github.com/2potatocakes/google_storage

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is to use the google_oauth2 Omniauth strategy instead of the google strategy.  This will pull the project name from the branding information you setup with Google.